# In Rails, how do I run certain tasks on shutdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I maintain a connection to a RabbitMQ server. When I safely turn the Rails Server off (via CTRL+C or whatever), how do I trigger a close to that connection?

I need an 'On shutdown' trigger. Is there one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `puma` as your webserver you can add `on_worker_shutdown` as a callback and then execute a shell script or whatever else is needed to close the connection to RabbitMQ.